# create html list from array with levels

Tags: php, html

I have an array like this

```
array(){
     [0] => Object(
        lvl => 0,
        name ='1'
     ),
     [1] => Object(
        lvl => 1,
        name ='2'
     ),
     [2] => Object(
        lvl => 2,
        name ='3'
     ),
     [3] => Object(
        lvl => 1,
        name ='4'
     ),
     [4] => Object(
        lvl => 0,
        name ='5'
     ),
}
```

And I have to create multiple list in html (list like categories with subcategories etc) how can I do this?

Comment: Please try something and then ask the question. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php might help. though.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple list in html? Do you mean drop-down list or just plain text? Be more specific.

Comment: ehh you don't understand 

i want to create list with sublist something like
<pre>
1
...2
......3
...4
5
</code>

but i don't know how parse array for that's list

something what looks like [link](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/file/n3875586/SubCategories2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need list with ul, li tags, try to use this code. It should work.

```
$lastLvl = 1;
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $object) {
    if ($object->lvl < $lastLvl) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= ($lastLvl - $object->lvl); $i++)
            echo '</ul>';
    }

    if ($object->lvl > $lastLvl) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= ($object->lvl - $lastLvl); $i++)
            echo '<ul>';
    }
    echo '<li>', $object->name, '</li>';

    $lastLvl = $object->lvl;
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $lastLvl; $i++)
    echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $object) {
    echo '<p class="level', $object->lvl, '">', $object->name, '</p>';
}
```

You'll have to define classes (level1, level2, level3 ...) in CSS file then.

Or you can just use some sign for indention. Like this:

```
echo '<p>', str_repeat('-', $object->lvl), $object->name, '</p>';
```