# PHP array with levels to HTML tree

Tags: php, html, algorithm

I have an array in php that looks kind of like this:

```
array[x][0]=item name
array[x][1]=level
```

so, for example,

```
array[0][0]="Node 1"
array[0][1]=0
array[1][0]="Node 2"
array[1][1]=0
array[2][0]="Node 2.1"
array[2][1]=1
array[3][0]="Node 2.1.1"
array[3][1]=2
array[4][0]="Node 2.2"
array[4][1]=1
```

I need to turn it into an html ul list, but one that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" /><span>Node 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" /><span>Node 2</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" /><span>Node 2.1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"><span>Node 2.1.1</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" /><span>Node 2.2</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The biggest catch is the position of the `</li>` tag - it needs to be after the next `<ul>` tag.  So it's `<li>` current node `<ul><li>` child node `</li></ul></li>`.  It's that last `</li>` that gets me.

This format is necessary to work with the jquery plugin I'm using (https://github.com/daredevel/jquery-tree).

I've seen the suggestions here: [create html list from array with levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027649/create-html-list-from-array-with-levels) but that doesn't work due to the extra

.

I think there's a solution to this using recursion and array slicing, but that seems inefficient.  So far, my attempts at an iterative solution have failed...

Comment: change your array structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to convert your array to a nested HTML list (`echo nestedHtmlList($array);`)

```
function nestedHtmlList($array) {
    $depth = 0;
    $result = "";
    foreach ($array as $node) {
        $newDepth = $node[1];

        if ($newDepth > $depth) {
            $result .= "<ul><li>";
        } else if ($newDepth < $depth) {
            for ($d = $newDepth; $d < $depth; $d++) {
                $result .= "</li></ul>";
            }
            $result .= "</li><li>";
        } else if ($result == "") {
            $result .= "<ul><li>";
        } else {
            $result .= "</li><li>";
        }
        $result .= "<input type='checkbox' /><span>";
        $result .= $node[0];
        $result .= "</span>";

        $depth = $newDepth;
    }

    while ($depth > 0) {
        $result .= "</li></ul>";
        $depth -= 1;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell me what you think:

**Code**

```
$array = [];
$array[0][0]="Node 1";
$array[0][1]=0;
$array[1][0]="Node 2";
$array[1][1]=0;
$array[2][0]="Node 2.1";
$array[2][1]=1;
$array[3][0]="Node 2.1.1";
$array[3][1]=2;
$array[4][0]="Node 2.2";
$array[4][1]=1;

function makeList( &$array, $level = null ) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    $html .= '<li>Level: ' . $level;
    while( $element = array_shift( $array ) ) {
        if( $level == $element[1] ) {
            $html .= '</li><li><label><input type="checkbox"/> ' . $element[0] . '</label>';
        } else if( $level < $element[1] ) {
            array_unshift( $array, $element );
            $html .= makeList( $array, $element[1] ) . '</li>';
        } else {
            array_unshift( $array, $element );
            break;
        }
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}

echo '<pre>';
echo makeList($array);
```

**Output** (human rendered html :D)

```
Level: 
[] Node 1
[] Node 2
Level: 1
    [] Node 2.1
    Level: 2
        [] Node 2.1.1
    [] Node 2.2
```